# Apache-Camel: camelcontext does not seem to work

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, apache-camel

Details:

JARs used - camel-core-2.5.0.jar , camel-spring-2.5.0.jar

Application server: Websphere 8.5 (has java se 7)

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd 
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.5.0.xsd
  ">

    <camel:camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <camel:package>com.myapp.routes</camel:package>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

and we have a file that extends routebuilder

```
public class SomeRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

...
...

public void configure() throws Exception {

...
...

from("file://E:/somedirectory/".process(new FileWaitProcessor()).process(new Processor() {
```

Doesn't work. Nothing is happening. It's supposed to detect file placed in a certain folder and process it. No exceptions were seen in the logs and no error in the xml config file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I assume you're talking about a web application. Maybe you haven't configured your web.xml properly(ContextLoaderListener). see http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-on-using-camel-in-a-web-application.html for more information.

Comment: i already did all that was stated there. ContextLoaderListener is already set in web.xml

Comment: is SomeRouteBuilder inside com.myapp.routes package?

Comment: yup it is inside com.myapp.routes